# Text with combinedClickable placed to upper edge of the row?

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-text

I have the following in a Row with other text.  Other text are positioned normally - center vertical, but this one is pushed to the upper edge.  What's wrong?

Update: more complete code:

Not sure how to get by this complaint:

"It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details."

```
Row {
    SelectionContainer(
        modifier = Modifier
            .padding(10.dp)
            .weight(1f)
    ) {
        Text(
            text = "a word",
            textAlign = TextAlign.Center,
            fontSize = dimensionResource(dimen.subtitle_size).value.sp,
            fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold,
            modifier = Modifier
                .clickable {
                    playAudio()
                }
        )
    }
    DividerHorizontal()
    Text(
        text = "test",
        modifier = Modifier
            .padding(end = 5.dp)
            .combinedClickable(
                onClick = {
                    onClick()
                },
                onLongClick = {
                    onLongClick()
                }
            ),
        textAlign = TextAlign.Center,
        fontSize = dimensionResource(dimen.normal_text).value.sp,
    )
    DividerHorizontal()
    TagSpinner(::addTag)
}



@Composable
fun DividerHorizontal() {
    Divider(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxHeight()
            .width(1.dp)
    )
}
```

It doesn't allow including more code?

```
@Composable
inline fun TagSpinner(crossinline addTag : (String) -> Unit) {
    Box(
        modifier = Modifier
            .padding(horizontal = 10.dp)
    ) {
        var expanded by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
        val tags: MutableList<String> = ArrayList(20)
        tags.add("All")
        if (tagTokens.isNotEmpty())
            tags.addAll(listOf(*tags()))
        Button(onClick = { expanded = !expanded }) {
            Text("Tag")
        }
        DropdownMenu(
            expanded = expanded,
            onDismissRequest = { expanded = false },
        ) {
            tags.forEachIndexed { index, label ->
                DropdownMenuItem(onClick = {
                    expanded = false
                    addTag(tags[index])
                }) {
                    Text(text = label)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide code for the entire `Row`. The code you provided is not sufficient for others to see the problem.

Comment: updated with code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing in your layout is actually positioned to center vertically. Text `"a word"` may appear so because it's enclosing composable, called `SelectionContainer`, has `.padding(10.dp)` set. This property pushes mentioned text away from top edge, thus appearing to be centered. Of course, if the height of the composable is just right. If you use a preview, it is obvious that it is not centered vertically. Here is the preview I used:

[image: Composable preview]

In order to have composables centered vertically, I suggest doing something like this:

```kotlin
Row(
    modifier = Modifier
        .wrapContentHeight(),
    verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically,
) {
    SelectionContainer(
        modifier = Modifier
//            .padding(10.dp) - this is not needed anymore
            .weight(1f)
    ) {
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

You also need to change your `DividerHorizontal` into this:

```kotlin
@Composable
fun DividerHorizontal() {
    Divider(
        modifier = Modifier
            .height(IntrinsicSize.Max)
            .width(1.dp)
    )
}
```

I believe the result is much closer to what you are trying to achieve:

[image]